# Unable to catch error from subscribe Angular RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I follow the latest tutorial, it use `pipe`, `tap` and `catchError` to intercept the result.

I have:

```
getStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<boolean>('/status').pipe(
        tap((returnedStatus: boolean) => console.log(returnedStatus)),
        catchError(console.log('getStatus error'))
    );
}
```

When an error happen, the `catchError` works, and the `console.log('getStatus error')` is executed and a message is printed.

**However**, when I `subscribe`, and place another error handler function in the `subscribe`, the function never executed even if error occurred.

```
getStatus().subscribe(
    st=> {
        console.log('data received: '+ st);
    },
    st => {
        console.log('yeah, error appear');
    }
)
```

Whenever data received, the `console.log('data received: ' + st)` will be executed, even though if an error occurs.

I know it is related to `pipe` and `catchError`, everything work well if I remove the `pipe`. How can I **carry forward** the error and let it be seen in the `subscribe`?

Comment: `catchError` should return an observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your catchError catches the error, at that point it no longer will continue down.  If you want it to continue to go down to your lower error handling, you need to return an Observable error.